# Смешивание MVVM и MVP

Tags: android, mvvm, архитектура, mvp

Я новичок, учусь. Хотелось бы выстраивать архитектуру правильно.
Расскажите, можно ли смешивать MVVM и MVP в одном проекте (будет ли это нормально со стороны нормальной разработки).

1. У меня есть активити, где я должна просто следить за изменениями данных (отображаю данные, соответственно наблюдаю за LiveData - MVVM)
2. Есть активность, где наблюдение за данными совсем не нужно, там я произвожу добавление данных (удобно было бы использовать MVP).
   Расскажите как правильно построить архитектуру в данном случае.
   Какие примеры вижу посредством гугления - не совсем нахожу ответ на конкретно мой случай, а опытного человека рядом нет, чтобы спросить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вашу задачу можно реализовать и с применением MVVM, и MVP. Смешать конечно (но не взбалтывать!) можно, но какой в этом смысл? Я бы даже сказал, оно где-то сбоку, и MVVM не про то, как часто, или каким способом VM будет всасывать обновленные данные из модели.

У меня больше опыта в MVVM, поэтому ниже сказанное - в контексте MVVM.

Грубо говоря, в модели все должно выглядеть так, чтобы это можно было удобно читать/писать в источник данных, а во вью-модели так, чтобы это можно было легко и удобно скармливать интерфейсу. Принято, что за преобразования представления данных модели в представление интерфейса отвечает вью-модель, там по идее и должна жить и трудиться логика преобразования данных. А модель - это всего-лишь интеграция с внешними источниками данных, и она отвечает за то, чтобы эти данные были доступны, и обновлялись по запросу или по любым другим правилам, в том числе инициированным самим источником (например Firebase).

Да и вообще, паттерн программирования - это рекомендация, особенно для новичков, чтобы не запутаться и писать вменяемый код (туда же SOLID в копилку). Опытный программист может хоть свой собственный шаблон реализации придумать, и сделать оптимально для себя.

Но следует учитывать, что если проект планируется поддерживать нескольким разработчикам, то тому, кто только что пришел в проект, будет проще понять код, если он написан с помощью какого-то одного определенного популярного шаблона, чем если там будет намешано, даже если и грамотно.

Попробуйте поглубже вникнуть не конкретно в то, как реализовывать MVP/MVVM, а в то, для чего это делается. И если ваша потребность не конфликтует с целями, поставленными перед шаблоном, то можете спокойно приступать к реализации тем способом, который считаете наиболее оптимальным.

По рекомендациям: если можете использовать MVVM (доступны ли биндинги?) - используйте MVVM, если не можете, используйте MVP.

Comment: поняла, большое спасибо :)